# Errors Installing Data Migration 2.2.0 Tool with Composer

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, data-migration-tool

Running the different commands below and getting errors with each of them. How do I get the data migration tool to install?

I also pasted in our composer.json file below.

**First Attempt**

This one says data-migration-tool 2.2.0 requires magento/framework ~101.0.0. But It doesn't want to install with my version of php.

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.0
----
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- magento/framework 101.0.9 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 101.0.8 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 101.0.7 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 101.0.6 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 101.0.5 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 101.0.4 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 101.0.3 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 101.0.2 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 101.0.1 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 101.0.0 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.18) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.2.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/data-migration-tool 2.2.0 requires magento/framework ~101.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.0, 101.0.1, 101.0.2, 101.0.3, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 101.0.6, 101.0.7, 101.0.8, 101.0.9].
- Installation request for magento/data-migration-tool 2.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/data-migration-tool[2.2.0].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**Second Attempt**

This one says don't install magento/framework ~101.0.0 but then to install it?

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.0 --ignore-platform-reqs
----
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 102.0.1) -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.1].
- Installation request for magento/data-migration-tool 2.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/data-migration-tool[2.2.0].
- Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 101.0.0
- Can only install one of: colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.1, v1.3.4].
- Can only install one of: colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4, v1.4.1].
- Can only install one of: colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4, v1.4.1].
- Conclusion: install magento/framework 101.0.0|install colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.3.4
- Installation request for colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract (locked at v1.4.1) -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.1].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**More Info**

The composer update command seems to work fine and it updates everything. Only issues with that is that it tells me phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned.

```
composer update
----
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-enterprise-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2.18"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "algolia/algoliasearch-magento-2": "^1.11",
        "ethanyehuda/magento2-cronjobmanager": "^1.8",
        "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~2.3.13",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1",
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.3.1",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missed the rule about version number matching your magento version number.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html
[image: Version number must match]

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.1
----
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing magento/data-migration-tool (2.3.1): Downloading (100%)
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No 
replacement was suggested.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Answer (score 0):

check your magento2 version :

```
php bin/magento --version
```

data migration tool version must be same as magento2 version

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<version>
```

if your M2 version 2.3.3 use

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.3
```